# Word shuffling problem - permutation with repetition

Tags: probability, permutations

We have the word TARANTULA
and the question asks:
If the letters are randomly shuffled, find the probability of: the first three letters include no A’s;

My take:
$P = \frac{\#\;of\;accepting\;possibilities}{\#\;of\;all\;possibilities}$

$\#\;of\;all\;possibilities= \frac{9!}{3!*2!} = 30 240$

$\#\;of\;accepting\;possibilities= 6*5*4\;(9\;letter\;excluding\;3\;A's)\;*\;6!\;(3\;letters\;are\;added)  = 86400$

However this would give P>1 which is impossible and also apparently in the correct answer the nominator is the same, but denominator is 9! which I don't understand, why would I have to use the formula for permutations and not permutations with repetitions.
Thank you!

Comment: If you are going to count "accepting possibilities" like that, then  the corresponding number of "all possibilities" is $9!$

Comment: If you want to undistinguish them, you need to divide both figures by $3! \times 2!$.  Your choice: $\dfrac{6\times5 \times 4 \times 6!}{9!}$ or  $\dfrac{\frac{6\times5 \times 4 \times 6!}{3!\times2!}}{\frac{9!}{3!\times2!}}$

Comment: @Henry oh that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a question asks for the *probability* of some arrangement, you should prick your ears, as there is generally a much simpler way to arrive at the solution.

Here, the first $3$ letters must be drawn from the $6$ non-T's, thus $Pr = \dfrac69\cdot\dfrac58\cdot\dfrac47$

Comment: That's a good trick, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome ! $\;$ (-: